# Set height of section in fullpage.js

Tags: html, css, height, fullpage.js

I am using [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)
This may sound very noobish, but can't figure how to set a section to have a height of less than 100%, I have tried setting it in the css using `.section` and `#section1` (eg. `height: 80%;`), but this has no effect...

Many thanks.

Max

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same question [was answered in the plugin's github issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/628).

> This is a FULL PAGE plugin.
> There's no such option

It is not an option the plugin offers.
If you want to do it, you would need to do it by yourself. Probably by overwriting the `height` property of the sections and slides after the plugin is rendered (on the `afterRender` callback) and after it gets resized (`afterResize`).

You can try it with by adding CSS styles as well, by adding things like:

```
#section1,
#section1 .fp-slide,
#section1 .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

## UPDATE

Now fullpage.js provides a way to create smaller sections than the viewport (or even bigger ones when using `autoScrolling:false` or `scrollBar:true`.

Adding the class `fp-auto-height` on each section will do it as stated [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-or-bigger-sections).

## UPDATE 2

`fp-auto-height` won't allow you to use percentages, but there's an extension that gives you that possibility. [Offset Sections](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/offset-sections.html).
It also allows you to show the section in the middle of the view-port showing parts of both the previous and the next one.

Comment: could you please update the answer's link to the current now: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-or-bigger-sections thank you! I have voted this up!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with I changed

```
$(window).height();
```

to 
`var windowsHeight = $('.universal-container').height();`

so lets say we have 4 divs

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class= "1st-div-holder">
</div>
<div class= "2nd-div-holder">
    <div class= "section">
        <div class= "universal-container">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now on our css we can do something like this

```
.main-comtainer{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


.1st-div-holder{
height:10%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}

.2nd-div-holder{
height: 90%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

this way the height is automatically picked up without taking up the whole window.